# How to Insert arraylist having multiple object in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, arraylist

I'm very new to Struts2 & Hibernate and I have the following question:

During the exception caught during the execution **unknown entity java.util.arraylist**

While i have create DAO & Pojo Using Hibernate Reverse Engineering. So i did Not Made any changes in Pojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package basic;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/basic/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        students.add(new Student("Michael"));
        students.add(new Student("Dave"));
        students.add(new Student("Tom"));
        students.add(new Student("Dinesh"));
        students.add(new Student("Lakshman"));
        students.add(new Student("Cruise"));

        session.save(students);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

}
```